# Uncaught Invariant Violation: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

**Admin Dashboard Setup:**

```
// React modules
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import { progressDone } from 'utils/nprogress-func';

// Admin Header section
import AdminHeader from '../admin-header/admin-header';


// Admin dashboard styling
import './styles/admin-dashboard';

class AdminDashboard extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    progressDone();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(!localStorage.getItem('admin_log_toks')) {
        browserHistory.push('/admin-login');
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (
        <div className="admin-dashboard">

          {/* admin-bg class has been styled in main.scss */}
          <div className="admin-bg"></div>

          <AdminHeader />

          <main>
            <div className="admin-content-wrapper">
              {this.props.children}
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      browserHistory.push('/admin-login');
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
    }
  }
}

// These props come from the application's
// state when it is started
function mapStateToProps(state) {

  const { authAdmin } = state;
  const { isAuthenticated } = authAdmin;

  return {
    isAuthenticated
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminDashboard);
```

I have an admin dashboard with a Navigation Menu.

`<AdminHeader />` consists of the menu which routes to various admin sections and gets loaded using AdminDashboards `{this.props.children}`.

I arrive on the admin dashboard through a login form and an action is dispatched which sets the variable isAuthenticated to true. isAuthenticated is then made available to all components through the reducers on successful login. isAuthenticated is set based on the token received from the server and then the token is stored in the browser's localStorage.

But, I also wanted to check what happens if the user deletes the token from the localStorage.

I have set the

```
funtion auth (state = {
  isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false
})
```

Now, if the user manually deletes the localStorage, then on refresh the user is sent back to the login screen. But, I am developing a single page app and I wanna confirm whenever the user routes to another route/url without refresh then the token in the localStorage still exists.

Hence, I wrote this code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('admin_log_toks')) {
    browserHistory.push('/admin-login');
  }
}
```

But, I get the error **Uncaught Invariant Violation: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.**

So I changed it to:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('admin_log_toks')) {
    browserHistory.push('/admin-login');
  }
}
```

Still I get the same error. So, I changed the above code to:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('admin_log_toks')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      browserHistory.push('/admin-login');
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

Everything worked but for some reason I don't think this is the right method.

I first tried solve this issue on route change:

```
browserHistory.listen(location => {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('admin_log_toks')) {
    browserHistory.push('/admin-login');
  }
})
```

But listen was firing twice or thrice on just a single route change.

**Is the above code correct, or is there a better way to resolve it? Basically, I just wanna route to login if anyone manually deletes the token from localStorage.**

I am using the latest version of React, React router, Redux and React redux.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: have you tried 'onEnter' hook in `react-router` route ?

Comment: @PhiNguyen Yes, I have. But, I may have to add it to all the routes. I have found a way. I'll post it as an answer soon.

Comment: waiting for that answer...